# how to chage X axis factor and put latex in it ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

```
y1<-c(10,13)
coef<-c('coef1', 'coef2')

data<-data.frame(y1, coef)

ggplot(data,
       aes(y=y1, x=coef))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="lightblue")+
  scale_x_discrete(lables=
                     c("coef1"= TeX("$\\beta_{5}$"),
                      "coef2"=TeX("$\\beta_{6}$"))
                       )
```

I think the problematic part is the last code

```
scale_x_discrete(lables=
                     c("coef1"= TeX("$\\beta_{5}$"),
                      "coef2"=TeX("$\\beta_{6}$"))
                       )
```

the x-axis, I put categorical variables which have two-level
(coef1 and coef2). and for the plot,
I want to change coef1 to beta5, and coef2 to beta5 (but latex)

so I used TeX function in latex2exp package, but it seems not to work.

Comment: please provide a sample of your data `reg2` and also `beta3_list`.

Comment: @shafee IT cannot. it is too big. I Will make a reproducible minimum example. but, my point is how to put latex in x axis. just give me some minuites

Comment: Try with `labels=` instead of `lables=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo `lables` in `scale_x_discrete`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

y1<-c(10,13)
coef<-c('coef1', 'coef2')

data<-data.frame(y1, coef)

ggplot(data,
       aes(y=y1, x=coef))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="lightblue")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=
                     c("coef1"= TeX("$\\beta_{5}$"),
                       "coef2"=TeX("$\\beta_{6}$"))
  )
```

[image: without typo plot]